# I got "The identity used to sign the executable is no longer valid." only when offline

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

We have an app on iPad Air wifi model running ios 9.2 that worked fine since February. At 28th June the app starts to crash on startup when the ipad is not connected to the Internet.

The app starts up fine when connected to the Internet, and once it started up once, we can close it, disconnect the Internet and can now launch it normally offline.

When we adhoc the app to another iPad running ios12, the app launches fine offline. The client wants this fixed without updating the os.

This is the log when it crashed.

```
Jul  7 11:28:02 iPad networkd[90] <Notice>: -[NETClientConnection effectiveBundleID] using process name securityd as bundle ID (this is expected for daemons without bundle ID
Jul  7 11:28:02 iPad securityd[87] <Error>: CFReadStream domain: 12 error: 8
Jul  7 11:28:02 iPad SpringBoard[53] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Jul  7 11:28:02 iPad SpringBoard[53] <Notice>: MIS: Using empty blacklist.
Jul  7 11:28:02 iPad networkd[90] <Notice>: -[NETClientConnection effectiveBundleID] using process name securityd as bundle ID (this is expected for daemons without bundle ID
Jul  7 11:28:02 iPad securityd[87] <Error>: CFReadStream domain: 12 error: 8
Jul  7 11:28:02 iPad SpringBoard[53] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Jul  7 11:28:02 iPad SpringBoard[53] <Notice>: MIS: Using empty blacklist.
Jul  7 11:28:02 iPad securityd[87] <Error>:  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
Jul  7 11:28:02 iPad securityd[87] <Error>:  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
Jul  7 11:28:02 iPad networkd[90] <Notice>: -[NETClientConnection effectiveBundleID] using process name securityd as bundle ID (this is expected for daemons without bundle ID
Jul  7 11:28:02 iPad securityd[87] <Error>: CFReadStream domain: 12 error: 8
Jul  7 11:28:02 iPad amfid[164] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Jul  7 11:28:02 iPad amfid[164] <Notice>: MIS: Using empty blacklist.
Jul  7 11:28:02 iPad securityd[87] <Error>:  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
Jul  7 11:28:02 iPad networkd[90] <Notice>: -[NETClientConnection effectiveBundleID] using process name securityd as bundle ID (this is expected for daemons without bundle ID
Jul  7 11:28:02 iPad securityd[87] <Error>: CFReadStream domain: 12 error: 8
Jul  7 11:28:02 iPad amfid[164] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf AnchorTrusted]
Jul  7 11:28:02 iPad amfid[164] <Notice>: MIS: developer cert trust result = 5
Jul  7 11:28:02 iPad amfid[164] <Error>: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/B670C369-644B-4A4A-AE35-0D42231058C3/FloorMap.app/FloorMap not valid: 0xe8008018: The identity used to sign the executable is no longer valid.
Jul  7 11:28:02 iPad com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.d-jps.FloorMap[0xc74c][200]) <Notice>: Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9
Jul  7 11:28:02 iPad assertiond[62] <Warning>: Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 200: (os/kern) failure (5)
Jul  7 11:28:02 iPad SpringBoard[53] <Warning>: Unable to register for exec notifications: No such process
Jul  7 11:28:02 iPad SpringBoard[53] <Warning>: Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 200: (os/kern) failure (5)
Jul  7 11:28:02 iPad SpringBoard[53] <Warning>: Unable to obtain a task name port right for <FBApplicationProcess: 0x15f7e4a10; com.d-jps.FloorMap; pid: 200>
Jul  7 11:28:02 iPad SpringBoard[53] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.d-jps.FloorMap[0xc74c]' exited abnormally via signal.
Jul  7 11:28:02 iPad SpringBoard[53] <Warning>: Application '(null)' exited for an unknown reason.
```

Comment: How is the app provided to the client machine? Ad hoc?

Comment: If this app is ad-hoc signed it has probably just expired; Install a new build

Comment: The app was installed by ad-hoc. 
The expiration date is 23rd Feb 2022. The app launches fine if connected to the Internet

Comment: After some time Apple needs to check that your provisioning profile is still in good standing. Your device needs to be connected to the Internet to do this

Comment: Where can I read about this?